# Makefile regex replace

Tags: c#, regex

I'm attempting to replace some paths in a `Makefile` using `Regex.Replace`.

Currently there are ~200 lines in the `Makefile` that look like this:

> $(OBJ_DIR)\tif_dir.obj: $(SRC_DIR)..\lib\libtiff\export\tiffconf.h $(SRC_DIR)..\lib\libtiff\export\tif_config.h

I've only shown two dependencies above but there are any where from 6 - 12 per line.

I'm attempting to remove the path portion of each of the dependencies so that the lines look like this:

> $(OBJ_DIR)\tif_dir.obj: $(SRC_DIR)\tiffconf.h $(SRC_DIR)\tif_config.h

First I was matching on the variables:

```
\p{Sc}(\W\w+[_]\w+\W)
```

I was then trying to use negative look ahead to remove the path portions between the `/` but leaving anything that contained `.h` or `.obj`

```
(?!.h|.obj)(\\.*\\)
```

This, of course does not work. It matches everything up to the last `header` file on the line.

How can I replace each of the paths in the `Makefile` with `\`,
so that each dependency path looks like this:

> $(SRC_DIR)\tiffconf.h

Instead of this:

> $(SRC_DIR)..\lib\libtiff\export\tiffconf.h

EDIT:
The paths specified are unique.

Comment: Are the paths different for each? i.e. ...\lib\libtiff\export\ differs?

Comment: @gtgaxiola yes, a lot of the paths are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\$\([A-Z]+_DIR\))(?:\\[^\\\s]+)*(\\\w+\.(?:h|obj)\b)", "$1$2");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5C%24%5C%28%5BA-Z%5D%2B_DIR%5C%29%29%28%3F%3A%5C%5C%5B%5E%5C%5C%5Cs%5D%2B%29*%28%5C%5C%5Cw%2B%5C.%28%3F%3Ah%7Cobj%29%5Cb%29&i=%24%28OBJ_DIR%29%5Ctif_dir.obj%3A%20%24%28SRC_DIR%29%5C..%5Clib%5Clibtiff%5Cexport%5Ctiffconf.h%20%24%28SRC_DIR%29%5C..%5Clib%5Clibtiff%5Cexport%5Ctif_config.h&r=%241%242)

**Details**

- `(\$\([A-Z]+_DIR\))` - Group 1: `$`, `(`, 1+ uppercase ASCII letters, `_DIR)`
- `(?:\\[^\\\s]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of:

  - `\\` - a `\` char
  - `[^\\\s]+` - 1+ chars other than `\` and whitespace
- `(\\\w+\.(?:h|obj)\b)` - Group 2: `\`, 1+ word chars, `.` and `h` or `obj` after followed with a word boundary.

The replacement is `$1$2`, the values of Group 1 and 2.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
\$\((OBJ_DIR|SRC_DIR)\)((.*?).obj|(.*?).h)
```

[Test Regex](https://regex101.com/r/jltM8X/2)

And you need to replace Group 2 which should be removing everything up to the last dash:

I used:

```
.*[\\]
```

I don't have a C# implementation, but here is a stand alone Java example how I would replace Matching Group 2

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class SandBox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "$(OBJ_DIR)\\tif_dir.obj: $(SRC_DIR)..\\lib\\libtiff\\export\\tiffconf.h $(SRC_DIR)..\\lib\\libtiff\\export\\tif_config.h";
        String regex = "\\$\\((OBJ_DIR|SRC_DIR)\\)((.*?).obj|(.*?).h)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        System.out.println("Original:\n"+text);
        while(m.find()) {
            String group2 = m.group(2);
            String untilSlash = ".*[\\\\]";
            group2 = group2.replaceFirst(untilSlash, "\\\\");
            text = text.replace(m.group(2), group2);
        }
        System.out.println("Result: \n" + text );
    }

}
```

The output I get:

```
Original:
$(OBJ_DIR)\tif_dir.obj: $(SRC_DIR)..\lib\libtiff\export\tiffconf.h $(SRC_DIR)..\lib\libtiff\export\tif_config.h
Result: 
$(OBJ_DIR)\tif_dir.obj: $(SRC_DIR)\tiffconf.h $(SRC_DIR)\tif_config.h
```